# Three.js - How can I set up a callback on a clickable region - 3 js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I started with this [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-beginners-guide-to-three-js) and successfully managed to export my 3D model from blender to a json file which in turn was displayed on my html page using three.js. The 3d model is basically a simple human. Now I would like to define some clickable regions on the model (these clickable regions might be hands,legs,chest etc). I wanted to know what would be the best way to do that so that I would know which region is clicked. Will I have to define these regions in blender ? Are there any other approaches out there for accomplishing this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[look at this example showing object highlighting based on mouse position.](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_cinematic)